# Как сделать ребилд только изменённых файлов Angular 2 и Cordova для разработки в live-режиме?

Tags: node.js, angular2, cordova

Проделал следующее:

```
cd Projects
ng new App
cd App
npm install nodemon --save-dev
cordova create cordova com.company.app "App"
cd cordova
cordova platform add browser
```

App/package.json:

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng:build": "ng build --target=production --environment=prod --output-path=cordova/www/",
    "build:browser": "npm run ng:build && cd cordova && cordova build browser",
    "build:android": "npm run ng:build && cd cordova && cordova build android",
    "dev:browser": "nodemon --exec \"npm run ng:build && cd cordova && cordova run browser\"",
    "dev:android": "nodemon --exec \"npm run ng:build && cd cordova && cordova run android\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0"
  }
}
```

Теперь nodemon билдит заново проект при каждом изменении. Как ускорить ребилд?

Answer (score 0):

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others \"ng build --output-path=cordova/www/ --watch\" \"cd cordova && mkdirp www && phonegap serve\"",
    "ng:build": "ng build --target=production --environment=prod --output-path=cordova/www/",
    "build:browser": "npm run ng:build && cd cordova && cordova build browser",
    "build:android": "npm run ng:build && cd cordova && cordova build android",
    "build:ios": "npm run ng:build && cd cordova && phonegap remote login && phonegap remote build ios",
    "build:windows": "npm run ng:build && cd cordova && cordova build android"
  }
```